# Prove that the order in $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}^*$ is this

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $o_{n}(a)$ be the order of $a$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.
Suppose that $a,m,n$ are relative primes, prove that $o_{mn}(a)=lcm(o_m(a),o_n(a))$.

I did the following: Suppose that $d=o_{mn}(a)$, then $a^d\equiv1$ $mod$ $mn$.
Then $a^d\equiv1$ $mod$ $n$ and $a^d\equiv1$ $mod$ $m$. So $o_m(a),o_n(a)|d$, so $lcm(o_m(a),o_n(a))|d$. But I think that this is incorrect and I dont know to prove the equiality.

Thanks for all ;)

Comment: You need to prove the other direction too (or restructure so your arrows are bidirectional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved one direction. But the arrows reverse so we can prove both in parallel, i.e.

$$\begin{align} a^k\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{mn}
&\iff a^k\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{m\ \&\ n}\\
&\iff o_m(a),o_n(a)\mid k\\
&\iff \ell := {\rm lcm}(o_m(a),o_n(a))\mid k
\end{align}$$

Thus $\,\ell= {\rm ord}_{mn}(a)\ $ since $\,k=\ell$ in $(\Leftarrow)$ yields $\,a^{\ell}\equiv 1\pmod{mn},\,$ and also $\ell$ is the *least* such $k$ since $\ell$ divides every other such $k$ by $(\Rightarrow)$.